# Remote access to my WAMP server from phone and pad

Tags: mobile, wamp

Hi im trying to access my localhost from my mobile and ipad and i'm getting the error forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server.

Answer (score 0):

sorry apparently its bad to do this please please refer to this post instead

[Accessing website files and phpmyadmin in wamp from another computer on lan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401995/accessing-website-files-and-phpmyadmin-in-wamp-from-another-computer-on-lan)

Answer (score -1):

hi if anyone else has this problem i eventually fixed it.

open httpd.conf located in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf this will be slightly diff depending on where you installed wamp and your apache version

use notepad++ or your favourite editor, search for:

# onlineoffline tag

and add this

Require all granted

it should then look like this:

# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted

hope that helps