# How to access my localhost website on android phone?

Tags: android, apache, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a website with bootstrap and in my Laptop browser it worked perfectly, but I want to view it in my SAMSUNG NOTE II and here what I have tried:
I have create a New Inbound Rules with port 80 and in httpd I have changed from
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
to 
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from All
I use cmd to get ip address and paste in laptop browser it works but, in phone browser it doesn't work. it says You don't have permission to access/ on this server.
What is wrong with this?
Thank very much for help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable your windows firewall or configure your network as home network.
2. Verify your ip address and the gateway.
3. Ping to the ip of the server
4. Try also with another laptop or desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Order Allow,Deny

Allow from all

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Apache, exit XAMPP control panel.
2. find and remove Remove the following portion from your **httpd-xampp.conf** file.

   `<LocationMatch "^/(?i:    (?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
           Require local
       ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </LocationMatch>`
3. Save it
4. start XAMPP control panel, Start Apache
5. on your mobile, browse to `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/file.php` where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is the ip address of the machine running Apache.

Comment: I use wamp server not XAMPP

Comment: no issues, both come with latest version of Apache and have similar procedures. I personally prefer XAMPP. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19412808/2534513

Comment: I use WAMP server version 2.5 and now I solved it by change from Require local =>Require all granted.(:

Comment: great! simple solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps:

- connect your laptop and android in the same wifi, find out your server's wlan ip(for me , its : 192.168.0.103)
- type `192.168.0.103` in your laptop's browser
- type `192.168.0.103` in your SAMSUNG's browser(chrome)
- type `192.168.0.103` in your android code , commonly use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

which step goes wrong?